# How to disable dropdown list item in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am a beginner to AngularJS and I am making a web app that needs to disable exiting values in a dropdown list.

I know how to do it in jQuery.  It is just like this: http://jsfiddle.net/qiushibaike/FcLLn/

But I don't really know how to do it in AngularJS, Should I try to disable the item or hide it? Can I set a value

HTML

```
<select ng-model="numbers.value" required>
     <option ng-repeat="item in items"> {{item.name}} </option>
</select><br/>
```

JavaScript

```
$scope.numbers= {};

$scope.items = [
    { id: 1, name: '11111'},
    { id: 2, name: '22222'},
    { id: 3, name: '33333'}
];
```

If I have something like this, how can I disable or hide the option 2 and 3 by AngularJS like what I did by using jQuery?

Comment: suggest learning how to filter and use filter instead of disable

Comment: This will help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22005601/how-can-i-disable-to-select-the-particular-option-from-angularjs-dropdown

Answer (score 2):

This is also possible with ngOptions.

You just need to add "**disable when**" in your ng-options tag.

In your case, you can also do like this

HTML

```
    <select ng-model="numbers.value" 
    ng-options="var.name as var.name disable when var.disabled for var in items" required>
      <option value="">-- Select --</option></select>
```

Javascript

```
$scope.items = [
    { id: 1, name: '11111'},
    { id: 2, name: '22222', disabled: true },
    { id: 3, name: '33333', disabled: true }
]
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ihUKEojvsoms6lZj7FZP?p=preview)

If you want to disable any option dynamically from your code,

here is a [Plunkr : Dynamic Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/doIGPIa8KJRBnhPTBJKJ?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

Use Angular's [ngDisabled](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angDisabled) directive.

HTML

```
<select ng-model="numbers.value" required>
    <option ng-repeat="item in items" ng-disabled="item.disabled"> {{item.name}} </option>
</select>
```

Javascript

```
$scope.items = [
    { id: 1, name: '11111'},
    { id: 2, name: '22222', disabled: true },
    { id: 3, name: '33333', disabled: true }
]
```

Comment: As for now, there is no possibility to set disabled options with `ngOptions` directive - there is a corresponding issue https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/638. So you should use `ngRepeat` instead.