# How can I disable to select the particular option from Angular JS dropdown?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-select

I want to disable a particular option from AngularJS dropdown.

It should be listed in the dropdown but should not allow it to be selected. So i need to disable it.

**MyFile.tpl.html**

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedFruits" 
        ng-options="fruit as fruit.name for fruit in fruits">
</select>
```

**MyController.js**

```
$scope.fruits = [{'name': 'apple', 'price': 100},{'name': 'guava', 'price': 30},
                 {'name': 'orange', 'price': 60},{'name': 'mango', 'price': 50},
                 {'name': 'banana', 'price': 45},{'name': 'cherry', 'price': 120}];
```

Here all the fruit names should be listed in the dropdown but **mango** and **cherry** should be disabled and should not allow the user to select it.

Is it possible? If possible, please let me know the solution please.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/alalonde/dZDLg/5/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`select` options are disabled with `disabled` attribute. Since `ng-options` doesn't support disabling, you'll have to generate options within `ng-repeat` and set [ng-disabled](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) based on requirements.

Template:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedFruits">
    <option
        ng-repeat="fruit in fruits"
        ng-disabled="disabledFruits.indexOf(fruit.name) !== -1"
        ng-value="fruit">
         {{fruit.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Inside controller:

```
$scope.disabledFruits = ["mango", "cherry"]
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/yozanimi/2/edit?html,js,output).

Answer (score 4):

Just came across this and it worth mentioning that this is possible as of Angular version 1.4.0-rc.1

here are docs [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

and some conversations [Angular Github](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/638)

```js
var app = angular.module("testApp", []);

app.controller("testController", function($scope) {
  $scope.people = [{
    "id": "0",
    "name": "Homer",
    "surname": "Simpson",
    "isDisabled": false
  }, {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Peter",
    "surname": "Griffin",
    "isDisabled": false
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Philip",
    "surname": "Fry",
    "isDisabled": false
  }, {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Humpty",
    "surname": "Dumpty",
    "isDisabled": true
  }, ];

  $scope.myPerson = $scope.people[2];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="testApp">

<head>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.1/angular.js"></script>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="testController">
  <select ng-model="myPerson" ng-options="person.name disable when person.isDisabled for person in people">
  </select>
</body>

</html>
```

and [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3au8NS4bVVZWZhIkb1P1)

If you set disabled value as default it wont work and you will see blank selected item instead.