# How to restrict dropdown to choose only one value using angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I have dropdown in which options are coming from array using ng-repeat. It is working as normal drop-down. But I want in a different way. If one option is selected, it should be disabled in the other dropdowns. can we do like that in angular?

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="address in addresses">
        Billing State:
        <select
            ng-model="address.state"
            ng-options="state.lookupCode as state.description for state in lov_state"></select>
        <tt>State selected: {{address.state}}</tt>
    </div>

</div>
```

controller code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.addresses = [
        {'state': 'AL'},
        {'state': 'CA'},
        {'state': 'FL'}
    ];

    $scope.lov_state = [
        {'lookupCode': 'AL', 'description': 'Alabama'},
        {'lookupCode': 'FL', 'description': 'Florida'},
        {'lookupCode': 'CA', 'description': 'California'},
        {'lookupCode': 'DE', 'description': 'Delaware'}
    ];
});
```

Please help me to do that. Here is the jsfiddle link.

https://jsfiddle.net/santhosh1a32/3vd7hyrq/

Comment: This might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22005601/how-can-i-disable-to-select-the-particular-option-from-angularjs-dropdown . You can use similar concept.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `disable` option provided in `ng-options` it self by using `disable when condition` in a place before `for` keyword.

```
<div ng-repeat="address in addresses">
  Billing State:
  <select ng-model="address.state" ng-change="checkSelected(address.state)" 
    ng-options="state.lookupCode as state.description disable when (address.state != state.lookupCode && state.selected) for state in lov_state">
  </select>
  <tt>State selected: {{address.state}}</tt>
</div>
```

[**Demo Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/E0yu9XAxqjxpwArBfDbK?p=preview)